# Can I remove a grass tile in Harvest Moon GBC?

Tags: harvest-moon-gbc

I've planted a grass tile by mistake where I was planning on putting some crops. I tried cutting them out, but no cigar.

Can I remove the grass or I'll just have to live with it?

Comment: I recall that you can "unplant" stuff by dropping a fence post on it.  The square can't have already grown stuff on it, though, so if the grass is full grown, use a scythe to harvest it first.

Comment: When you say "tried cutting them out" what tools did you use? Did you only try the scythe? What about the Hoe?

Answer (score 1):

When it is fully grown, cut it, then use your hoe.